# How To Create Leaderboard For An Firebase Anonymous User?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, leaderboard

I am creating an Android Game where it has a **leaderboard** to show user scores with their *name, profile pic* and *score* as a list item.

Later I decided to remove **Google login** implemented the game in order to increase the user flow into the game play page. But at the same time I wanted to have the users authenticated (for security) without asking them to click on a login button (where so many drop off is happening). So I found **Anonymous authentication** option in Firebase authentication section.

My question is when I relay only on  **Anonymous login** throughout the game do I need to have to convert the **Anonymous User** to a **Google User** programmatically to show them in the **leaderboard** list or Google handles this automatically/internally?

**Current Working flow**

Step 1: Connect Google Client Api (see below written code)

Step 2: Authenticate with Firebase (Google Sign in method)

Step 3: Show Leaderboard

**Current implementation**

When I open leaderboard activity where I have the following code to show the leadeboard (here the user is authenticated by Google SignIn method),

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new 
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .build();

    // [END config_signin]
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();
...
...
...

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    GoogleSignInResult result = 
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

    if (result.isSuccess()) { 
       // Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
      GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
      firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
    }
}
...
...
...

//On Button Click.......
public void submitScore(long score) {

   if (isGoogleAPIConnected()) {
      Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.my_leaderboard), score);
   }
}
```

The above written code is working well with Google Authentication method.
Can I use the same above code when I use **Anonymous authentication** method also?

Reference:: [Authenticate Using Google Sign-In on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)

Comment: We have no way to answer this without seeing at least a minimum piece of code that shows how the leaderboard works.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have modified the question with code of the current implementation that i have done with Google Sign In method. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The leaderboard has no connection to firebase account, so only thing i have to make sure is to have Google api connected with GAME API scope. The leaderboard will show up based on the connected Google account irrespective of he is using anonymous or linked firebase account.